# How to print an HTML tag in a JTextPane with html content type in Java

Tags: java, html, xml, tags, jtextpane

I am creating an **`XML`** editor with Java and I am using **`JTextPanes`** to show the content of the **`XML`**.
The content type of the **`JTextPanes`** is **`"text/html"`** so it is skipping all of the **`XML`** tags that I want to appear in the pane.
Here is most of the **`JTextPane`** class:

```
public class Label extends JTextPane {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6151945111760925061L;

    public Label(String text) {
        setContentType("text/html");
        setText(StringOperations.toHtml(text));
        setEditable(false);
        setBackground(null);
        setBorder(null);
        setFont(new Font("Eras Bold ITC", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    }

}
```

Here is the method that converts the plain text to html.

```
public static String toHtml(String text) {
    return ("<html>" + text + "</html>");
}
```

So for example when I insert:
 **`"<resource>4</resource>"`**

The output is **`"4"`**.

What I want is for the output to be
**`"<resource>4</resource>"`**.

I tried doing:

```
return ("<html>" + text.replace("<","/<") + "</html>");
return ("<html>" + text.replace("<","\"<\"") + "</html>");
```

But the tags are still unreadable.

Could you tell me how can I escape the **`'<'`** and **`'>'`** characters?

Comment: You are undertaking a rather advanced task.  You should at least read through the HTML specification, including [HTML Document Representation - Character Entity References](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.3.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to create custom EditorKit and set it to JTextPane,

for example :

https://www.boplicity.nl/knowledgebase/Java/Xml+syntax+highlighting+in+Swing+JTextPane.html